# Determine if one string is a rotation of the other Python

Tags: python

After thinking for a long hard time, learning about algorithms to find substrings, and coming to really long and tedious code I decided against my solution and to look for help. The solution was much simpler and elegant. After determining that my code was too much for a simple task I came across an explanation of a simple way to find if one string was a rotation of the other. Man I feel dumb for falling down a long rabbit hole however I learned much about many different things and also how to keep it simple stupid. Previous post of this problem [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/190634/compare-two-lists-to-see-if-one-is-a-rotation-of-the-other-2).

```
#rotated list

def is_rotated(lst1, lst2):
    ''' Is lst2 a rotation of lst1'''
    str1, str2 = ''.join(map(str,lst1)), ''.join(map(str,lst2))
    if not len(str1) == len(str2):
        raise ValueError("Lengths not equal")

    if str2 in (str1 + str1):
        return True
    return False

# rotation
lst1, lst2 = [1,2,3,4,6,4,7], [6,4,7,1,2,3,4]
assert is_rotated(lst1, lst2)

# rotation with repeated numbers
lst1, lst2 = [1,2,3,4,6,4,7,1], [6,4,7,1,1,2,3,4]
assert is_rotated(lst1, lst2)

# different set
lst1, lst2 = [1,2,3,4,6,4,6], [6,4,7,1,2,3,4]
assert not is_rotated(lst1, lst2)
lst1, lst2 = [1,2,3,4,6,4,7], [6,4,6,1,2,3,4]
assert not is_rotated(lst1, lst2)

# equal
lst2 = lst1
assert is_rotated(lst1, lst2)

# empty
lst1, lst2 = [], []
assert is_rotated(lst1, lst2)


# 1 empty, 1 not empty
lst1, lst2 = [], [1]
assert not is_rotated(lst1, lst2)
lst1, lst2 = [1], []
assert not is_rotated(lst1, lst2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good work! This is certainly primarily an improvement from your previous implementation. However, there are still a few problems.

1. Don't raise an error when passed two lists of differing length. Not only is this unexpected by users, it breaks some of your tests.

   ```python
   # 1 empty, 1 not empty
   lst1, lst2 = [], [1]
   assert not is_rotated(lst1, lst2)
   lst1, lst2 = [1], []
   assert not is_rotated(lst1, lst2)
   ```
2. The pattern of `if condition return True else return False` should be replaced with `return condition`. This is easier to read and reduces the amount of code you have to write!
3. Joining the lists of integers with the empty string as a separator is dangerous. If I pass in `[1, 23]` and `[12, 3]` the function will incorrectly return `True`. If the function only has to handle integers, you can easily fix this by using a comma (or any other character) as a separator. (Just remember to include it when checking if the string is contained in the other string `str1 + ',' + str1`)

I would prefer a more general solution that works for lists containing any type of element. Using Nas Banov's answer [from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3314913/7186598) to handle the sub list check, this is a really simple function to write.

```python
def contains_sublist(lst, sublst):
  n = len(sublst)
  return any((sublst == lst[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(lst)-n+1))

def is_rotated(lst1, lst2):
  if not len(lst1) == len(lst2):
    return False
  return len(lst1) == 0 or contains_sublist(lst2 * 2, lst1)
```